# Difference between amd quad core and i7 processors

Tags: cpu

I would like to know the difference between AMD  quad core processor and i7 processor. Which one of them is best suited for high end programming needs?

Comment: @Sathya: I am sorry to ask this, but why was this closed? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: you're asking 2 questions at once, and this -> "best suited for high end programming needs?" isn't [really a good question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: @Sathya : Thanks for the clarification, if I would have known I would have edited the question :) instead of letting being closed...That was bit disappointing...In case I haven't got an answer yet, I would have been forced to ask the same question again with more precise explanation on "high end programming needs" or just forget the question ;) Some courteousness would be of help..Thanks!

Comment: The [faq] clearly means shopping recommendations [are off-topic and likely to be closed](http://superuser.com/faq#shopping) and what sort of questions [not to ask](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask). Closing the question isn't the be-all, aned all, you can still edit it and flag for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intel Core i7 2600K - 3.4GHz - 1MB L2 - 8MB L3
vs
AMD Phenom II X6 1100T BE - 3.3GHz - 2MB L2 - 6MB L3](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/Product/287?vs=203)

This website will allow you to compare selected processors and see different results in certain scenarios.